# Postalcode masked in eBay FindingService API

Tags: ebay-api

**Postalcode** was seen to be masked since yesterday for **FindingService API** for operation-name **findItemsAdvanced**. The postalcode was seen as-is before. Any means of getting the as-is postalcode through eBay **FindingService API** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've also seen this issue recently when using the ebay API.

Most annoyingly It seems ebay have changed their policy for sharing presale information - possibly due to their interpretation of data protection.

The issue is discussed with reference to the ebay UI here: https://community.ebay.co.uk/t5/Buyer-Central/Buyers-can-no-longer-see-sellers-postcode-on-any-item-WHY/td-p/6249678